# How to Get the Children values from Inspect Tool for desktop UI Element

Tags: pywinauto, inspect, web-inspector, inspector

Hi For my desktop automation. I need to fetch the FirstChild, LastChild, Next, Previous, Children values.
Please help me how to get those values in pywinauto and if possible give me python program for this.

Please find the yellow color highlighted for fetch the data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq5G6.png)

I don't have any idea to get this.